# creating debian package

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I have checked on debian site for creating a package.

But, it is not easy to understand as it does not give a step wise processes.

Please help me how to create a Debian package.

If possible a detailed steps would be very fine.

Comment: I thinks it's too late but soon you can use this graphical program to create your own debian package, [debpac](https://github.com/thibDev/debpac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link i got for creating a debian package.

Hope this will help you all guys...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=51003

Regards,
iSight

Comment: Yup... i got it after registration only.. its a forum... u can get queries and answers only when u registered there.. its free of course...

Comment: It turned out to be a decent resource. Although the need for registration is a bit of a bummer.

Answer (score 5):

The goal is to create a package that simply puts a shell script where I want it.

1.Create a directory to build your packages in. Some use "deb" and others use "packages". Others create a directory structure for making multiple packages under "deb" (or whatever).

```
    mkdir deb
```

2.Create the directory structure in deb that represents where you want the script to be placed1

```
mkdir -p ./deb/usr/local/bin
```

3.Copy the script into your new directory

```
cp /path/to/my/script/myscript.sh ./deb/usr/local/bin/
```

4.Make a subdirectory called "DEBIAN", this will host the package control file.

```
mkdir -p ./deb/DEBIAN
```

5.Create a control file.

```
touch ./deb/DEBIAN/control
```

6.Open the control file and enter the text below.

`Package: myPackagename (no spaces or underscores allowed) 
 Priority: optional 
 Section: misc 
 Maintainer: Maintainer Name 
 Architecture: all 
 Version: 1.0
 Depends: package1, package2, ......... 
 Description: short description here long description here (don't remove space at the beginning of line) (replace this with an empty line)`

7.Change ownership

```
Change ownership: sudo chown -R root:root ./deb
```

8.Create the debian package.

```
dpkg -b ./deb /my/output/destination/packagename.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code or source code in tar.gz, you can use the following:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

In the source code, compile it:

```
./configure
make
```

And then build the debian package with checkinstall, for example:

```
sudo checkinstall --install=no --pkgname=XXX --pkgversion=0.X.X --maintainer=YOU_XXX
```

The debian package is in the same directory :)