# How to add uninstall script to debian package

Tags: python, debian, ubuntu-16.04

I have created a simple debian package for my python program using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623684/creating-debian-package/25720058#25720058). 
I am also using a `postinst` script to setup and populate `mysql` tables. The package gets installed with following command.

```
sudo apt install mypackage.deb
```

I now want to add an uninstall script so that if the package is removed, uninstall script gets called to cleanup the environment.

How can I incorporate uninstall script with the debian package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to write a postrm script too the same way as you wrote the postinst script. See [maintainer scrips flowcharts](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#maintainer-script-flowcharts) to understand how these scripts work.

A quote from the same article:

"It is possible to supply scripts as part of a package which the package management system will run for you when your package is installed, upgraded or removed.

These scripts are the control information files **preinst**, **postinst**, **prerm** and **postrm**. They must be proper executable files; if they are scripts (which is recommended), they must start with the usual #! convention. They should be readable and executable by anyone, and must not be world-writable."